# In Kusto/KQL, how do I select any rows from one table that contain a key from any row in another table?

Tags: kql

I have a table, let's say "users".

| userid | fname | lname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mike | row |
| 2 | Sally | forth |
| 3 | Engl | Ish |

I have another table, let's call it "teams". That table has full team information as so:

| teamId | members | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 31 | [{"UserId":1},{"UserId":2}] | Deck |
| 32 | [{"UserId":7}] | Bridge |
| 43 | [{"UserId":8},{"UserId":3}] | Anchor |

I need to search teams for only the rows that contain any of the users in the users table, but I'm trying to reduce the search space so I don't have to pull in and transform the entire teams table.

In SQL, I could simply do this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users WHERE (
   SELECT * FROM teams where teams.members contains users.userid)
```

(or basically, I know I'm cheating with using contains above, but you get the idea)

Bottom line, how do I get the following from the above two tables using Kusto:

| userid | teamId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 31 |
| 2 | 31 |
| 3 | 43 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this, using `mv-apply` and `lookup`:

```
let users = datatable(userid: long, fname: string, lname: string)
[
    1, 'Mike', 'row',
    2, 'Sally', 'forth',
    3, 'Engl', 'Ish',
]
;
let teams = datatable(teamid: long, members: dynamic, name: string)
[
    31, dynamic([{"UserId": 1}, {"UserId": 2}]), 'Deck',
    32, dynamic([{"UserId": 7}]), 'Bridge',
    43, dynamic([{"UserId": 8}, {"UserId": 3}]), 'Anchor'
]
;
users
| lookup (
    teams
    | mv-apply m = members on (project userid = tolong(m.UserId))
    | project userid, teamid)
    on userid
| project userid, teamid
```

| userid | teamid |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 31 |
| 2 | 31 |
| 3 | 43 |

> *I'm trying to reduce the search space so I don't have to pull in and transform the entire teams table*

the way to do this is to change the schema of the table before or at ingestion time. for example, you can use an [update policy](https://y0nil.github.io/kusto.blog/blog-posts/update-policies.html) in order to transform it once, at ingestion time, and not have to do it over and over again each time you run a query (as done by the query above)